# How to control two Data Table values to write XML vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, datatable

There is a result of `SQL query` where I get paperBoy data along with payments done to the guy `(cash,check or both cash and check)`

DataTable looks like:

```
ID Name    Payment  cashInfo1  cashInfo2  CheckInfo1  CheckInfo2
1  Rivera  Cash     xx         xx         null        null   
1  Rivera  Check    null       null       dr          o1    
1  Rivera  Both     xx         yy         rr          rr    
2  Gomez   Cash     xx         xx         null        null   
2  Gomez   Cash     xx         xx         null        null      
2  Gomez   Both     xx         yy         rr          rr
```

I want an XML based on that like

```
<All>
   <PaperBoy>
      <Name>Rivera</Name>
      <CashPayment> 
          <cashInfo1>xx</cashInfo1>
          <cashInfo2>xx</cashInfo2>
      </CashPayment>
      <CheckPayment> 
          <CheckInfo1>dr</CheckInfo1>
          <CheckInfo2>o1</CheckInfo2>
      </CheckPayment>
      <Both> 
         <CashPayment> 
             <cashInfo1>xx</cashInfo1>
             <cashInfo2>yy</cashInfo2>
         </CashPayment>
         <CheckPayment> 
             <CheckInfo1>rr</CheckInfo1>
             <CheckInfo2>rr</CheckInfo2>
         </CheckPayment>
      </Both>
   </PaperBoy>
   <PaperBoy>
      <Name>Gomez</Name>
      <CashPayment> 
          <cashInfo1>xx</cashInfo1>
          <cashInfo2>xx</cashInfo2>
      </CashPayment>
      <CashPayment> 
          <cashInfo1>xx</cashInfo1>
          <cashInfo2>xx</cashInfo2>
      </CashPayment>
                <Both> 
         <CashPayment> 
             <cashInfo1>xx</cashInfo1>
             <cashInfo2>yy</cashInfo2>
         </CashPayment>
         <CheckPayment> 
             <CheckInfo1>rr</CheckInfo1>
             <CheckInfo2>rr</CheckInfo2>
         </CheckPayment>
      </Both>
   </PaperBoy>
</All>
```

to do so I created a method to open and close Root and other to handle the paperBoy logic

```
Public Sub myMethod(ByVal XmlDocumentPath As String)
        Try
            Dim XmlWriter As New Xml.XmlTextWriter(XmlDocumentPath, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
            XmlWriter.Formatting = Xml.Formatting.Indented 
            XmlWriter.WriteRaw("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>")
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("All")
            handlePaperBoy(XmlWriter)
            XmlWriter.WriteFullEndElement() '</All>
            XmlWriter.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox( ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub




Private Sub handlePaperBoy(ByRef XmlWriter As XmlTextWriter)   
   Dim dT As New Data.DataTable 'supposing I filled it already
    Dim currentId = "-1"
    For Each DR As DataRow In dT.Rows
        If currentId <> DR.Item("ID") Then
            currentId = DR.Item("ID")
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PaperBoy")
            XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", DR.Item("Name"))
            Select Case DR.Item("Payment")
                Case "Cash"
                     'add xml elements
                Case "Check"
                     'add xml elements
                Case "Both"
                     'add xml elements
            End Select
            XmlWriter.WriteEndElement() '</PaperBoy>
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

However I got stuck at that point because to add `Paperboy` tags I use a flag to indicate if ID changed, but How could I control the `Payment` logic?

I think I would need to save `Paperboy` Data and then keep on looping until `ID` changed then fill corresponding tags.

What could I do to solve the issue?

Comment: so if the next id is same the payment tags will not be written.is that the problem?

Comment: thats right, the issue there is open and close tag of `<PaperBoy>` and all inner xml tags..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this code,

```
Dim dT As New Data.DataTable 'supposing I filled it already
Dim currentId = "-1"
Dim intcount as integer=0
 For Each DR As DataRow In dT.Rows
          If currentId <> DR.Item("ID") Then
            if intcount<>0    'dont end tag for first record
              XmlWriter.WriteEndElement() '</PaperBoy>
            end if
            currentId = DR.Item("ID")
            XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("PaperBoy")
            XmlWriter.WriteElementString("Name", DR.Item("Name"))
            Select Case DR.Item("Payment")
                Case "Cash"
                     'add xml elements
                Case "Check"
                     'add xml elements
                Case "Both"
                     'add xml elements
            End Select
       else 
            Select Case DR.Item("Payment")
                Case "Cash"
                     'add xml elements
                Case "Check"
                     'add xml elements
                Case "Both"
                     'add xml elements
            End Select
         End If

         if intcount=dT.Rows.count-1 ' end tag for last record
           XmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
         end if

         intcount+=1
    Next
```

hope this helps.

Comment: ya check out and please revert if any help needed.

Comment: Ok, I get the code, very nice way to solve the issue